# Jquery to pass values through href and get that value in that page

Tags: jquery

how can i pass the values through href link and get that values in that href link page.
here is the code am using

```
 var namee="samplename";
 $(location).attr('href','/home.html?names='+namee);
```

In my `home page` how can i get the value of `name`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: you can use `location.href.split('?')[1]`, you will get `names=somename`

Comment: i want to get somename only...not names=somename..how it is possible

Comment: what is the location inside $(location)?